# Blade template not executing @else clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a Blade template that loads a list of users and displays their various details.

If a user has no mobile number I want to display the message "No Mobile Number" (I've tried single and double quotes), this never gets displayed:

```
@if ($person->Mobile >= "")
    {{ $person->Mobile }}
@else
    'No Mobile Number' 
@endif
```

I tried substituting the "No Mobile" message with {{ $person->EMail }} (which I'm displaying elsewhere, so I know everyone has an email address), but still go nothing, as far as I can tell the logic isn't going into the @else block.
Any ideas?

Comment: it seems you have logic problem in your if statement

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul - Thanks, can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
@if (!empty($person->Mobile))
    {{{ $person->Mobile }}}
@else
    'No Mobile Number' 
@endif
```

Comment: any specific reason for using `{{{` `$person->Mobile` `}}}` braces??

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
@if( isset($error_message) )
    @section('content')
        @parent
    @stop
    @section('error_message')
        <strong>Holly molly! </strong><em>{{  $error_message  }} :(</em>
    @stop  
@endif
```

I have a section **content** and inside content have another section **error_message** so if `error_message` variable is set, show that **content** section and inside print my `error_message`.

PD: I haven't my original code to hand... Im currently using **Twig** as primary template engine in Laravel4. Twig *beats* Blade in simplycity and is very usefull

Comment: @axrwkr did you need more explanation?? or maybe create new thread for deeper discussion.

Comment: @axrwkr I did it now... and deleted previous comment...
BTW im currently blocked to add new Answers i dunno why?