# Laravel 4 else statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a problem. Blade is not executing the code within the @else statement. Here's my code (also, it's a table):

```
        @extends('base')
@section('title', 'Who is online?')
@endsection
@section('main')

<div class="doc-content-box">
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Vocation</th>
        <th>Date registered</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

    @if(!empty($results))
        <?php $count = 0;?>
        @foreach($results as $result) 
      <?php $count++;?>
      <tr>

        <td>{{ $count }}. </td>

        <td>{{ $result->name }}</td>

        <td>{{ $result->level }}</td>

        <td><?php if($result->vocation == 1){ 
echo "Sorcerer"; 
}else if($result->vocation == 2){
echo 'Druid';
}else if($result->vocation == 3){
echo 'Paladin';
}else if($result->vocation == 4){
echo 'Knight';
}else if($result->vocation == 5){
echo 'Master Sorcerer';
}else if($result->vocation == 6){
echo 'Elder Druid';
}else if($result->vocation == 7){
echo 'Royal Paladin';
}else{
echo 'Elite Knight';
}?></td>

        <td>{{ $result->created_at }}</td>

        <td><?php if($result->group_id == 1){ 
echo "Player"; 
}else if($result->group_id == 2){
echo 'Gamemaster';
}else if($result->group_id == 3){
echo 'God';
}?></td>

      </tr>
      @endforeach 
@else

<td>{{ "There are no users online." }}</td>

@endif
</tbody>

  </table>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

It just won't execute There are no players online. I've also tried adding it in between `<tr></tr>`, also viewed [Blade template not executing @else clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631445/blade-template-not-executing-else-clause/17634221#17634221) , tried something like: `<td>'There are no players online.'</td>`, but still it doesn't show up.

Also, am I able to switch all those php if statements with ternary operators? If so, how could I do it?

Comment: Just curious as to why you're mixing PHP with Blade here...

Comment: @Mike Anthony
I don't know why, I was about to use ternary operators but I couldn't manage to do it. Is there a way to use it all with blade? I'm kind of new to all of this..

Comment: Those have nothing to do with the difference between `<?php if(...` and `@if(...)`. What I suggest you do, is move your repetitive logic to a Controller, and make use of arrays for matching your result's group ID, and vocation. There's just too much repetitive logic in your view, which is not standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because your `if` statement is inside of your `foreach` statement and is therefore never executed. If you move your `foreach` inside of your `if` block, it should work.

--- More

I actually just had to do what you were doing and discovered the problem. You are calling `empty()` on `$results` which is an object and is not an array, it is a `Collection` object. The proper way is to use the `count()` method. So something like this:

```
@if($results->count() > 0)
    @foreach($results as $result)
        ...
    @endforeach
@else
    <p>Nothing found!</p>
@endif
```

Comment: here, I've edited my post to show you how have I done it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or anything? I can't see a reason why your code now doesn't work. Can you post what HTML it does return?

Comment: Here's what the HTML shows: http://paste.laravel.com/Fnz , also here's what it looks like: http://1.imgland.net/HpDZEZ.png

Comment: My only guess is that $results isn't what you are expecting. PHP is saying that it isn't empty, but it isn't iterable via foreach.

Comment: can you clarify it a bit? what should I do now?

Comment: Try adding `<?php var_dump($results); ?>` after your if statement to see what $results actually is.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$results->isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the way to write a ternary operators in blade template in laravel.

```
{{{$collectionObject->filed_name ==1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}}
```